# Why is my global variable object (window.[variable]) working locally but not live in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Junior dev here:

**Goal:** I would like to define my global variable [**array** of objects] in one JS file (**globalVariables.js**) and dynamically access that global variable's key values from different JS (**index.js**, **products.js**) and HTML (**index.html**, **products.html**, etc.) pages. I will include all of these pages at the bottom.

Essentially, on both **index.html** and **products.html**, I am listing my client's products, and the global variable is supposed to fill in all that information dynamically.

According to [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) section on Global Variables, I should be able to declare the variable like so:

```
var carName = "Volvo";
```

and access it like so:

```
console.log(window.carName)
```

**Unexpected Result**: Instead, nothing shows up in the browser and, looking at the console, I read:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property '0' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://tiegrrr.com/testing/js/index.js:19:54)
at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
at t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined
```

Furthermore, if I try defining the global variable like I've seen recommend on some websites...

```
var window.allProducts = [object, object, object, etc.]
```

...I get a different error in VS Code:

```
',' expected.ts(1005)
```

What am I missing? And why would it work locally but not online, given the directory structure is the same?

==================================================

**ALL THE FILES**

**globalVariables.js**

```
var allProducts = [
{
    name: 'TieGrrr Strap',
    img: 'tiegrrr-strap.jpg',
    desc: "TieGrrr Straps are the safest alternative to stretch and bungee cords. They quickly and securely hold cargo of almost any shape or size. Works great with ladder racks, pipe, lumber, kayaks, rafts, etc.",
    popularity:1,
    lengths: [3,6,9,12],
    colors: ["red","blue","orange","green"],
    breakStrengths: ["1,200 lbs"],
    cost: 5,
    tag:"tiegrrr",
    page: "tiegrrr-strap.html"
},
{
    name: 'Ratchet Strap',
    img: 'Ratchet-S-Hook.jpg',
    desc: '',
    popularity:2,
    lengths: [6,10,12,16],
    colors: ["red","blue","orange","green"],
    breakStrengths: ['1,500 lb.'],
    cost: 8,
    tag:"ratchet",
    page: "ratchet-strap.html"
},
{
    name: 'Heavy Duty Ratchet',
    img: 'heavy-duty-strap.jpg',
    desc: '',
    popularity:3,
    lengths: [6,10,12,16],
    colors: ["red","blue","orange","green"],
    breakStrengths: ['1,500 lb.','3,000 lb.'],
    cost: 10,
    tag:"heavy",
    page: "heavy-duty-ratchet.html"
},
{
    name: 'Load Hugger',
    img: 'load-hugger.jpg',
    desc: '',
    popularity:4,
    lengths: [6,10,12,16],
    colors: ["red","blue","orange","green"],
    breakStrengths: ['1,500 lb.'],
    cost: 15,
    tag:"hugger",
    page: "load-hugger.html"
},
{
    name: 'Super Duty Ratchet',
    img: 'SD Ratchet-F-Hook.jpg',
    desc: '',
    popularity:0,
    lengths: [6,10,12,16],
    colors: ["red","blue","orange","green"],
    breakStrengths: ['1,500 lb.'],
    cost: 12,
    tag:"super",
    page: "super-duty-ratchet.html"
},
{
    name: 'Winch Strap',
    img: 'winch-green.jpg',
    desc: '',
    popularity:0,
    lengths: [6,10,12,16],
    colors: ["red","blue","orange","green"],
    breakStrengths: ['1,500 lb.'],
    cost: 9,
    tag:"winch",
    page: "winch-strap.html"
},
{
    name: 'Universal Cam Strap',
    img: 'universal-strap1.jpg',
    desc: '',
    popularity:0,
    lengths: [6,10,12,16],
    colors: ["red","blue","orange","green"],
    breakStrengths: ['1,500 lb.'],
    cost: 6,
    tag:"uni",
    page: "universal-cam-strap.html"
},
{
    name: 'Endless Ratchet',
    img: 'endless-ratchet-strap.jpg',
    desc: '',
    popularity:0,
    lengths: [6,10,12,16],
    colors: ["red","blue","orange","green"],
    breakStrengths: ['1,500 lb.'],
    cost: 8,
    tag:"endless",
    page: "endless-ratchet-strap.html"
}
```

];

**indes.js**

```
$(() => {


let $container = $('#item-container')

// TODO: make it so LOOP automatically filters for 1-4

for (i=0;i<4;i++) { // LOOPS through first 4

    $newITEM_div = $('<div>') // PARENT div for ITEM + IMG
    $newITEM_div.addClass("item")
    
    $newITEM_NAME_div = $('<div>') // div for ITEM NAME
    $newITEM_NAME_div.text(window.allProducts[i].name)
    $newITEM_NAME_div.addClass("item-name")

    $newITEM_IMG = $('<img>')
    $newITEM_IMG.css("background-image", `url('../testing/images/${window.allProducts[i].img}')`);

    $newITEM_div.append($newITEM_NAME_div)
    $newITEM_div.append($newITEM_IMG)
    $newITEM_div.attr('onclick',`location.href='./products/${window.allProducts[i].page}'`);
    $container.append($newITEM_div)
    
}
```

})

console.log(window.allProducts)

**products.js**

```
$(() => {

let $container = $('#item-container')

// splits string at every "/" then POPS last array element
var currentPage = $(location).attr('href').split("/").pop();

// TODO: make it so LOOP automatically filters for 1-4 popularity

// on PRODUCTS page, this code loops through ALL PRODUCTS for category imgs
if (currentPage.match("products.html")) {
    for (i=0;i<window.allProducts.length;i++) {
        $newITEM_div = $('<div>') // PARENT div for ITEM + IMG
        $newITEM_div.addClass("product-item")
        
        $newITEM_NAME_div = $('<div>') // div for ITEM NAME
        $newITEM_NAME_div.text(window.allProducts[i].name)
        $newITEM_NAME_div.addClass("product-item-name")

        $newITEM_IMG = $('<img>')
        if (currentPage.match("products.html")) {
            $newITEM_IMG.css("background-image", `url('../testing/images/${window.allProducts[i].img}')`);
        } else {
            $newITEM_IMG.css("background-image", `url('../images/${window.allProducts[i].img}')`);
        }

        $newITEM_div.append($newITEM_NAME_div)
        $newITEM_div.append($newITEM_IMG)
        $newITEM_div.attr('onclick',`location.href='./products/${window.allProducts[i].page}'`);
        $container.append($newITEM_div)
        $container.removeAttr('id');
        $container.addClass("all-products-container")
    }

} else {

    for (i=0;i<window.allProducts.length;i++) {

        if (currentPage.includes(window.allProducts[i].tag)) {

            let currentProduct = window.allProducts[i]

            let $productImg = currentProduct.img;
            let $productTitle = currentProduct.name;
            let $productDesc = currentProduct.desc;

            let $productCost = currentProduct.cost;

            $("#product-image").attr("src",`../images/`+$productImg);
            $('h1').text($productTitle);
            $('#description').text($productDesc);

            for (i=0;i<currentProduct.lengths.length;i++) { // LOOPS through first 4
                $newLength = currentProduct.lengths[i]
                $newLength_div = $('<div>')
                $newLength_div.text($newLength)
                $newLength_div.addClass("length")
                $('.lengths').append($newLength_div)
            }

            for (i=0;i<currentProduct.colors.length;i++) { // LOOPS through first 4
                $newColor = currentProduct.colors[i]
                $newColor_div = $('<div>')
                $newColor_div.addClass("color")
                $newColor_div.css("background-color",`${$newColor}`)
                $('.colors').append($newColor_div)
            }

            for (i=0;i<currentProduct.breakStrengths.length;i++) { // LOOPS through first 4

                $newBreak = currentProduct.breakStrengths[i];
                if (i>0) {
                    $('#breaks').append(`, `+$newBreak);
                } else {
                    $('#breaks').text($newBreak);
                }
                
            }

            $('#cost').text(`$`+$productCost+`.00`);

            break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}

  })
```

**index.html** (head and body, StackOverflow didn't like the full doc for some reason)

```
<head>
<title>TieGrrr Straps, Inc.</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="author" content="TieGrrr Straps, Inc.">
<meta name="description" content="Manufacturers of high quality tie-down systems at competitive prices.">
<meta name="keywords" content="tie downs, tie-downs, tie down straps, ratchet straps, straps, tie downs, tie down systems, tie down manufacturers">

<!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- TieGrrr Strap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

<!-- add GOOGLE FONTS here-->
<link href="" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- ADD Google Font when ready-->

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- SLICK carousel -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<!-- Add the new slick-theme.css if you want the default styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>

<!-- JS for INDEX PAGE -->
<script src="js/globalVariables.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div id="top-thin-bar" class="col">800.810.8881 | sales@tiegrrr.com</div>
    </div>

</div>

<nav class="navbar sticky-top">
    <div id="main-logo" onclick="location.href='https\://tiegrrr.com'"></div>
    <div id="nav-info-content">
        <div id="main-logo-mobile" onclick="location.href='https\://tiegrrr.com'"></div>
        <div id="company-title">TieGrrr Straps, Inc.</div>
        <div id="subtitle">Manufacturers of Quality Tie-Down Systems</div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <div class="active" onclick="location.href='./index.html'">HOME</div>
            <div onclick="location.href='./products.html'">PRODUCTS</div>
            <div onclick="location.href='./about-us.html'">ABOUT US</div>
            <div onclick="location.href='./contact-us.html'">CONTACT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons-mobile"> <!-- starts out HIDDEN -->
        <div onclick="location.href='./index.html'">HOME</div>
        <div onclick="location.href='./products.html'">PRODUCTS</div>
        <div onclick="location.href='./about-us.html'">ABOUT US</div>
        <div onclick="location.href='./contact-us.html'">CONTACT</div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row" id="landing-carousel">
        <div id="carousel-container" class="col">
            
            <div id="carousel-inner">

                    <!-- CHANGE which PICS in STYLES.CSS -- look for #on-sale-item- -->
                    <div id="on-sale-item-1"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-2"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-3"></div>
                    
                    <div id="on-sale-item-1"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-2"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-3"></div>

                    <div id="on-sale-item-1"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-2"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-3"></div>
                    
                    <div id="on-sale-item-1"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-2"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-3"></div>

                    <div id="on-sale-item-1"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-2"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-3"></div>
                    
                    <div id="on-sale-item-1"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-2"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-3"></div>

                    <div id="on-sale-item-1"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-2"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-3"></div>

                    <div id="on-sale-item-1"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-2"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-3"></div>
                    
                    <div id="on-sale-item-1"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-2"></div>
                    <div id="on-sale-item-3"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center" id="page-content">
                <div id="item-container"> <!-- use JAVASCRIPT to LOOP through -->
                    
                    <!-- index.js fills in with TOP 4 POPULAR ITEMS -->

                </div>
    
                <a href="./products.html" class="btn btn-outline-warning tiegrrr-button" role="button">View ALL PRODUCTS</a>
    
                <p style="color:white; font-size:x-large; font-style:italic; font-weight:800;">GET A GRIP</p>
                <p style="color:white; font-size:1.2em; font-weight:600;">We are a family-owned manufacturing company that aims to provide tie-down systems both superior in quality and price to that of any similar products carried by "big-box" stores.</p>
    
                <p style="color:white; font-size:1em;margin-bottom:3vh;">All of our products meet or exceed both D.O.T. and Web &Sling Assoc. standards for safety. Before we will sell any product, it must pass our field and/or lab test for "normal" abuse. Our products may cost as much as other disposable tie-downs, but they will outlast even the most expensive straps.</p>
    
                <p style="color:red; font-size:large; font-style:italic; font-weight:800;">AMERICAN OWNED</p>
                <img id="USAflag" src="./images/USA.jpg">
    
            </div>

    </div>
</div>                        

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="footer">
            Copyright © 2007 Tiegrrr Straps, Inc.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<!-- SLICK carousel inline script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#carousel-inner').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 8000,
    });
</script>
</body>
```

**products.html**

```
<head>
<title>TieGrrr Straps, Inc. - Products</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="author" content="TieGrrr Straps, Inc.">
<meta name="description" content="Manufacturers of high quality tie-down systems at competitive prices.">
<meta name="keywords" content="tie downs, tie-downs, tie down straps, ratchet straps, straps, tie downs, tie down systems, tie down manufacturers">

<!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- TieGrrr Strap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

<!-- add GOOGLE FONTS here-->
<link href="" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- ADD Google Font when ready-->

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- JS for PRODUCTS PAGE -->
<script src="js/globalVariables.js"></script>
<script src="js/products.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div id="top-thin-bar" class="col">800.810.8881 | sales@tiegrrr.com</div>
    </div>

</div>

<nav class="navbar sticky-top">
    <div id="main-logo" onclick="location.href='https\://tiegrrr.com'"></div>
    <div id="nav-info-content">
        <div id="main-logo-mobile" onclick="location.href='https\://tiegrrr.com'"></div>
        <div id="company-title">TieGrrr Straps, Inc.</div>
        <div id="subtitle">Manufacturers of Quality Tie-Down Systems</div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <div onclick="location.href='./index.html'">HOME</div>
            <div class="active" onclick="location.href='./products.html'">PRODUCTS</div>
            <div onclick="location.href='./about-us.html'">ABOUT US</div>
            <div onclick="location.href='./contact-us.html'">CONTACT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons-mobile"> <!-- starts out HIDDEN -->
        <div onclick="location.href='./index.html'">HOME</div>
        <div onclick="location.href='./products.html'">PRODUCTS</div>
        <div onclick="location.href='./about-us.html'">ABOUT US</div>
        <div onclick="location.href='./contact-us.html'">CONTACT</div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- TODO: remove FLEX STYLES from ROW -->
    <div class="row">
        <div id="carousel-container" class="col">
            
            <div id="item-container"> 
                    
                <!-- PRODUCTS JS fills in -->

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center" id="page-content">
            <div style="margin-top: 2.5vh;">
            
                <p style="color:white; font-size:x-large; font-style:italic; font-weight:800;">GET A GRIP</p>
                <p style="color:white; font-size:1.2em; font-weight:600;">We are a family-owned manufacturing company that aims to provide tie-down systems both superior in quality and price to that of any similar products carried by "big-box" stores.</p>
    
                <p style="color:white; font-size:1em;margin-bottom:3vh;">All of our products meet or exceed both D.O.T. and Web &Sling Assoc. standards for safety. Before we will sell any product, it must pass our field and/or lab test for "normal" abuse. Our products may cost as much as other disposable tie-downs, but they will outlast even the most expensive straps.</p>
    
                <p style="color:red; font-size:large; font-style:italic; font-weight:800;">AMERICAN OWNED</p>
                <img id="USAflag" src="./images/USA.jpg">
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                        

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="footer">
            Copyright © 2007 Tiegrrr Straps, Inc.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

**UPDATE:** I incorrectly called `allProducts` an object when I first posted, but it's actually an **array of objects**, if that matters.

Comment: Check the definition of `allProducts` variable properly. It seems there is some syntax error

Comment: Far too much irrelevant code for a [mcve] to demonstrate your basic issue

Comment: I'll note that in the future @charlietfl - I guess as a junior dev, I wasn't sure if you needed all my .html to have anything to work with but I can see how this might be TMI.

Comment: No problem. We understand there is a learning curve here but I'm fairly sure this could have been summarized in probably less than 10 lines focused on the specific problem at hand. Too much noise makes it hard to discuss specifics and requires more effort than needed to isolate where an issue might be occuring

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding something to the window it's usually best to do it explicitly.

So your second solution was probably right but your syntax was wrong, try this:

```js
window.allProducts = {objectValues, objectValues, etc.}
```

Without the `var`. You only need to use `var` when creating the variable, since `window` already exists it'll error if you try and create it.

Comment: Hmm. Well, taking out the `var` _did_ resolve the ts(1005) error but I'm still getting `undefined` in my console.

Also, why have I received two downvotes for this post? Anything I can do to improve future posts?

Comment: @JB444, can you try this, copy the whole content of `globalVariables.js` and paste that in the browser console, and hit enter. Does that give any error?

Comment: Ignore the haters man, just do your thing. I can't see the index.js import in your html page. Make sure it's included in script tags.

Comment: @Wazeed - thanks for that suggestion! Logging it with `window.allProducts` returns an array as expected, but logging it in the console with `var allProducts` returns `undefined`!

Comment: @cd3k - oh, I thought I already had that covered with these lines on the various .html pages `<script src="js/globalVariables.js"></script>
<script src="js/products.js"></script>` --does that not work?